# Data Grid View Hyper Link in ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

Hi I am using DataGridView by mapping URL from database which i have given it in Hyperlinkfield (for eg: there will be 10-20 links will be displayed in the datagridview) if the particular person clicks the particular link then it has to redirect to that particular URL by incrementing the Count column in the Database for that particular URL.

Note : iam using the datagridview in the template design mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the row command event

create a dynamic click with the url you wish to give

Answer (score 0):

use CommandArgument and do your stuff in Gridview onrowcommand event.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("LinkID")%>' CommandName="btnUpdate" Text='<%#Eval("LinkDisplayText")%>'>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    if(e.CommandName=="btnUpdate")
    {
      int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
      //based on LinkID get the current click count from database.
      int icount;
      //increment the count
      //update the database once again and get the link as well.
      //redirect to the link
      Response.Redirect("");
    }
  }
```